# EF foreign-key property is non-nullable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two exact same database tables, one prod and one dev.
whenever i deploy to dev database, everything works fine. And prod database allows throw me this error with I tried to use EF & MVC to write data back to database.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
```

And of course I have checked this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2010/01/31/deleting-foreign-key-relationships-in-ef4.aspx

seems like there are no problems with my EF codes, purely db table issues
Anyway I can find more details ?

Comment: Could you please show these two tables?

Comment: Have you used Red-Gate SQL compare against the same tables, in case you are missing something? also, have you compared the data in there reference table?

Comment: i have compared the two tables, they are identical.

Comment: well, it turned out to be one of them doesn't have the foreign key in place. I have remove the code on removing an object from the entity. so everything works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Deleting Foreign-Key Relationships in EF4
good article on the issue
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2010/01/31/deleting-foreign-key-relationships-in-ef4.aspx